# How can i display Json data into HTML Div

Tags: html, json

I have json data and i have created Div into html file now i want to display into div
eg

```js
{
  "id": 1,
    "url": '/somefolder/selfie.png',
      "text": 'My Selfie'
}
{
  "id": 2,
    "url": '/somefolder/selfie2.png',
      "text": 'My Selfie 2'
}
```

```html
<div id="img-holder">
<img src="" />
<span id="img-txt"></span>
</div>
```

how can i repeat each data into div?

Comment: This sounds like you haven't done any of your own research. There is no broken code here that you're trying to fix.

Comment: Use JavaScript to add those JSON objects to an array and iterate through them to create your corresponding `div`s

Comment: `$.each(json, function(i, item) {
        $(".inner img").attr("src", json.image);
        $(".wrapper a h6").text(json.name);
    });​ `  like this